# How to check if a customer exists before adding them through the QuickBooks Online API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have successfully connected my ASP.NET MVC5 C# project to QuickBooks Online through Oauth, and the "IPP .NET SDK for QuickBooks V3" NuGet Package.

I can add new customers, and everything works fine. However, if I try to add a customer that already exists, it throws the following error: "ValidationException was thrown".

My question is, what is the best way to check if the customer already exists in QuickBooks before trying to add them, so as to avoid the exception?

This is the code I have that adds the new customer to QuickBooks:

```
OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret);
ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(realmId, intuitServicesType, oauthValidator);
DataService dataService = new DataService(context);

var customer = new Customer();

customer.GivenName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(submission.FirstName.ToLower());
customer.FamilyName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(submission.LastName.ToLower());
customer.BillAddr = new PhysicalAddress()
{
    Line1 = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(submission.Address.ToLower()),
    City = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(submission.City.ToLower()),
    CountrySubDivisionCode = submission.State,
    PostalCode = submission.ZipCode
};

customer.PrimaryEmailAddr = new EmailAddress() { Address = submission.EmailAddress.ToLower(), Default = true };
customer.PrimaryPhone = new TelephoneNumber() { FreeFormNumber = submission.Phone };

dataService.Add(customer);
```

---

**Editted to add my solution with the answer from @Keith Palmer**

```
OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret);
ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(realmId, intuitServicesType, oauthValidator);

// Check if the customer already exists in QuickBooks
QueryService<Customer> customerQueryService = new QueryService<Customer>(context);
int customerCount = customerQueryService.Where(c => c.GivenName == submission.FirstName && c.FamilyName == submission.LastName).Count();
if (customerCount == 0)
{
    // If not, then add the new customer.
    DataService dataService = new DataService(context);

    var customer = new Customer();

    customer.GivenName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(submission.FirstName.ToLower());
    customer.FamilyName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(submission.LastName.ToLower());
    customer.BillAddr = new PhysicalAddress()
    {
        Line1 = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(submission.Address.ToLower()),
        City = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(submission.City.ToLower()),
        CountrySubDivisionCode = submission.State,
        PostalCode = submission.ZipCode
    };
    customer.PrimaryEmailAddr = new EmailAddress() { Address = submission.EmailAddress.ToLower(), Default = true };
    customer.PrimaryPhone = new TelephoneNumber() { FreeFormNumber = submission.Phone };

    dataService.Add(customer);
}
else
{
    TempData["Warning"] = "The customer already exists in QuickBooks.";
    return RedirectToAction("Estimates", "Admin");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query for the customer to see if they exist before adding them.

What you query for (Name, Email, etc.) is dependent on how you want to implement your application/what your customer wants.

Per the docs:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0400_tools/0005_sdks/0010.net_tools/0030_query_filters

Your code should look something like this:

> IEnumerable customers = invoiceQueryService.Where(c => c.Balance > 1000);

You can refer to the object reference to see which fields you can filter by:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/customer

Comment: The specifics of how to do the query with the QuickBooks API is what I am after. I understand what I need to do, but I don't know how to do it using asp.net C#. Name or Email for the search would be fine with me, I just can't find the documentation of how to do either.

Comment: I added a code example and some additional links for you.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed! I've been through those intuit developer documents trying to find the solution for hours. Don't know how you found that :). I will update my question with the codeI implemented, in case someone else has the same question.

Comment: @RobertM.  Fortunately there's a thing called Google that let's us search and find the new links.  :-P   I have updated them!  Cheers!

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. quick question, are your contact forms functional on the website? Been trying to reach your on and off for months regarding the OpenCart solution you have...